# How to load large amount of data into a d3.js table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

Actually I have nearly 60,000 records in a "getcsv" file.Now I'm trying to load all these records into a d3.js table of "index.html" page.
The "index.html" page is taking lot of time to load the data into a d3 table.

My index.html code :

```
 d3.csv('getcsv', function(data) {
        var columns = ['client_ip']
        tabulate(data, columns)

        $('#example').DataTable({
          "pagingType": "full_numbers"
        });
      });
```

My getcsv and index.html are located at this 
url: http://plnkr.co/edit/AAiX3V5nL6q44BHkKrsj?p=preview.

My getcsv file  looks like this:(nearly 60,000 records)

```
client_ip
"192.168.7.123"
"192.168.7.102"
"192.168.7.83"
...
...
```

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

Comment: Can anyone please help me out ...

Comment: So you're trying to render a 60,000-record table? I'd guess that's what's taking so long as your example with a smaller number of records seems to run OK. The solution would be to only render what is displayed. I'm not sure if the DataTable plugin can help you with this or if you would have to do something custom.

Comment: Can u please explain,how to avoid the large amount of loading time while loading a "getcsv" file into a d3 table of "index.html" page.

Comment: The buzzwords here are *lazy loading* and *paging*, if you want to dig into that topic. I'd suggest you first load the page, then display a loading animation while fetching the first set of data with an ajax request.

Comment: To load the data it is taking nearly one minute of time.Can't we reduce the timespan to load the data into html page